processingで木の成長をうまく表現したい
入力された文字によって木を成長させたいのですがうまくいきません。描画した後にどうしても動き続けてしまうので気が成長したら動きが止まるようにしたいです。分かる方がおりましたらお助け願います。
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.HashSet;

int step = 12; // Number of steps
float tr_scale = 0.99; // Scale of branches
float tr_angle = 24.0; // Angle of branches
float tr_length = 180.0; // Initial branch length
float tr_startd = 0.0; // Starting angle
float offset = -90; // Angle offset
float tr_startx;
float tr_starty;
float currentLength;
String lastInput = ""; // Store the last input
PVector[] trees; // Array to store trees
int treeCount = 0; // Number of trees

void setup() {
    size(1200, 1000);
    background(0); // Set background to black
    tr_starty = height; // Set starting point at the bottom of the screen
    trees = new PVector[10]; // Maximum 10 trees
}

void draw() {
    background(0); // Reset background
    for (int i = 0; i < treeCount; i++) {
        drawTree(trees[i].x, trees[i].y, trees[i].z, tr_startd, step); // Draw each tree
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    if (key == ' ') {
        String input = promptForText("文章を入力してください:");
        if (input != null) {
            if (similarity(lastInput, input) > 0.5) {
                if (treeCount > 0) {
                    currentLength += random(10, 30); // Increase branch length
                    trees[treeCount - 1].z = currentLength; // Update the last tree's length
                }
            } else {
                if (treeCount < trees.length) {
                    currentLength = random(tr_length); // Initial length for a new tree
                    tr_startx = random(0, width);
                    trees[treeCount] = new PVector(tr_startx, tr_starty, currentLength); // Add new tree
                    treeCount++;
                } else {
                    for (int i = 1; i < treeCount; i++) {
                        trees[i - 1] = trees[i];
                    }
                    currentLength = random(tr_length);
                    tr_startx = random(0, width);
                    trees[treeCount - 1] = new PVector(tr_startx, tr_starty, currentLength); // Add new tree
                }
            }
            lastInput = input; // Save input
        }
    }
}

String promptForText(String message) {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
}

// Jaccard similarity function
float similarity(String a, String b) {
    HashSet<String> setA = new HashSet<>(java.util.Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));
    HashSet<String> setB = new HashSet<>(java.util.Arrays.asList(b.split(" ")));

    HashSet<String> intersection = new HashSet<>(setA);
    intersection.retainAll(setB);

    HashSet<String> union = new HashSet<>(setA);
    union.addAll(setB);

    return (float) intersection.size() / union.size(); // Jaccard similarity
}

// Draw tree function
void drawTree(float x01, float y01, float len, float deg, int n) {
    stroke(random(256), random(256), random(256)); // Random branch color
    strokeWeight(max(1, (n + 1) * 1)); // Set stroke weight based on recursion level

    float x02 = x01 + len * cos(radians(deg + offset));
    float y02 = y01 + len * sin(radians(deg + offset));

    line(x01, y01, x02, y02);

    if (n > 0) {
        float deg01 = random(-tr_angle, tr_angle);
        float scl01 = random(random(10, 20), len * tr_scale);
        drawTree(x02, y02, scl01, deg + deg01, n - 1);

        float deg02 = random(-tr_angle, tr_angle);
        float scl02 = random(random(10, 20), len * tr_scale);
        drawTree(x02, y02, scl02, deg + deg02, n - 1);
    }
}

